# GridSearchCV - which data should be used?

Tags: python, training-data, grid-search, gridsearchcv, train-test-split

I am currently working on a binary classification problem with about 2000 data points in the training set and I wonder if I should use the whole training set for gridsearch or if I should do a split first to generate validation data. I have the following 2 variants to choose from. The first one is with the split of train/val and the second one is without the split (GridSearchCV on whole training set)

**1. Variant**

Train/val split

```
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y, random_state=rs)
```

GridSearchCV on SVC **(only using x_train and y_train)**

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=splits, shuffle=True, random_state=rs)

params = {"C": [0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15]}
        
clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(random_state=rs), params, cv=skf, n_jobs=-1, scoring=monetary_score)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(grid.best_params_)
print(grid.best_score_, "\n")
print(grid.best_estimator_)
```

Using the validation set

```
final_clf = clf.best_estimator_

y_pred = final_clf.predict(X_val)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_val, y_pred)
print(cm)
```

**2. Variant**

GridSearchCV on SVC **(using the whole x and y)**

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=splits, shuffle=True, random_state=rs)

params = {"C": [0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15]}
        
clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(random_state=rs), params, cv=skf, n_jobs=-1, scoring=monetary_score)
clf.fit(X, y)

print(grid.best_params_)
print(grid.best_score_, "\n")
print(grid.best_estimator_)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly apply grid search cv without splitting the data into train and test splits as you did in the variant 2.
The reason for this is your dataset comprises only 2000 data points. Incase if you have a vast dataset in that case you may have to split the dataset into 90% training and 10% testing.
But for now you can continue with Variant 2